# Conversion of pandas df to R data.frame using rpy2 with mixed type columns

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

If I have a Pandas dataframe that contains a column with a mixture of character and numeric data, for example:

```
d = {'one' : pd.Series(['cat', 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
 'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])} 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

%%R -i df
str(df)
```

then when it is converted to an R data.frame using rpy2 each value in the mixed column is given its own column in the R data.frame, filled with the same value. The code above produces a data.frame with 5 columns, not 2:

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ one.a: chr  "cat" "cat" "cat" "cat"
 $ one.b: num  2 2 2 2
 $ one.c: num  3 3 3 3
 $ one.d: num  NaN NaN NaN NaN
 $ two  : num  1 2 3 4
```

Is this expected behaviour? If so why?

(I am using a Jupyter notebook 5.0.0 running on Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit) | Windows 10 and rpy2 2.9.1)

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using the latest release of rpy2. There were fixes about pandas conversion, most notably in rpy2-2.9.2 (see https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/changes.html)

Comment: Thanks @lgautier. I have now updated rpy2 to 2.9.4 (the most recent wheel I could find) but I am still seeing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like rpy2 is making an r listvector not an r stringvector.  I was running into a similar problem converting a dataframe some columns had both strings and NaN. Although I was using pandas2ri.py2ri() instead of R magic, I think they are similar.

This code seems to work.

```
# Your code with pandas2ri instead of rmagic
d = {'one' : pandas.Series(['cat', 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'two' : pandas.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])} 
df = pandas.DataFrame(d)

print(df)

pandas2ri.activate()
r_df = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)
print(r_df)

# convert each column individually to see the vector type in R
r_df1 = pandas2ri.py2ri(df['one'])
print(type(r_df1))

r_df2 = pandas2ri.py2ri(df['two'])
print(type(r_df2))

# Make an rpy2 OrdDict, be sure to include the None to avoid indexing problems
od = rlc.OrdDict([('one', robjects.StrVector(['cat', 2., 3., None])),
                  ('two', robjects.FloatVector([1., 2., 3., 4.]))])

# make a vector for rownames
od_rownames = robjects.StrVector(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

# convert the OrdDict to an r dataframe and assign rownames
od_df = robjects.DataFrame(od)
print(od_df)

od_df.rownames = od_rownames
print(od_df)
```

More info is available https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/vector.html#creating-objects